# How do I inline the contents of an external HTML document using XSLT?

Tags: html, xslt

I have an XSLT that I input to a 3rd party application.  This application displays the result of that XSLT as a web page in their application.

I have a dynamic HTML document that I want to display in that application.  How can I "read" the HTML document via an XSLT document such that whenever the html document is updated, the XSLT will read the new file?

If I'm not being clear, to convey the idea, my xslt would read something like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet>
    <xsl:output method="html"/>

    <xsl:template match="Something">
        <!-- Stuff is done here -->
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:ReadExternalDocument filePath="my/path/document.html" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I've come across the `Document()` function, but it seems to destroy my tags. That is, I would like to include the child tags of the parent element in the output.

Comment: To read an external file, the `document()` function is the way to go. Classic HTML won't work, you must provide XML input. Could you elaborate what "destroy my tags" means?

Comment: @Tomalak - I want to include the child tags of the parent element in my output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Tomalak suggested, the document function is the way to go.  I read in the external HTML document using the `document()` with the `copy-of` node.  `copy-of` does a deep-copy, including tags, to obtain the whole external HTML document.  The code looks like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet ... >
    <xsl:output method="html"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:copy-of select="document('ExternalDocument.html')"  />
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```